# Binding onClick function to the href attribute function of a tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

html part

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab2">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span9 offset1">
                <header id="second">
                    <strong>Users</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="span2">
            <div class="tabbable" align="center">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#mobile" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Mobile</strong>
                    </a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#BO" data-toggle="tab"><strong>BO</strong>
                    </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Here I want to bind `onClick` function to `BO`  tab using jQuery.

How can I do that ?

Comment: how is it different from your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438406/get-the-details-corresponding-to-particular-tab-on-click-of-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like,

```
$(function(){
   $('a[href="#BO"]').on('click',function(){
       alert('#BO called');
       // your code;
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give an id to the anchor tag  first.

ex :

```
<li><a id="tabClick" href="#BO" data-toggle="tab"><strong>BO</strong>

jquery :

$("#tabClick").click(function(){    

});
```

Comment: You should give a id  ????????, it's better to have an ID , but still he can select the element by 'href' attribute

Comment: yeas he can easily select it like this $('a[href="#BO"]')  . but I thought it ll be easy for him to use an ID or Class for doing this. cz I thought he is beginner.

Comment: You should give an id means , you should give an ID ;)

Comment: There are many ways to do one thing. I don't see any wrong with "should" here.

Comment: I can change the should as can . problem solved huh :D